# Flink checkpoint disabled and auto.offset.commit is false

Tags: apache-flink

We have flink app which consumes record from kafka and transform and produce to kafka.

We are using Flink version 1.16

Want to understand the behaviour of offset commit/management with below configuration .

1. flink checkpoint disabled
2. auto.commit.enabled = false
3. offset.reset = earliest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable both Flink checkpoints and Kafka Client auto committing, no offsets will be committed to Kafka. If you restart your Flink application, it will read from earliest everything you're starting it.

Comment: and what happens when offset.reset is latest

Comment: Then whenever you restart the job it will begin from the tail of kafka's log. (With checkpointing disabled, there's nothing Flink-specific about these answers. At that point, Flink is just another Kafka client.)